# Keys of shared memory segments are 0

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

This is the output of shmget -m on my linux machine. Here all the keys are 0.

[image]

Why is that so? How will the process which creates them distinguish them? Usually we create a key using ftok() and use them for creating a shared memory using shmget(). In that way we can distinguish the memory segments in our program. It seems that the OS is getting around without distinct keys. What might be going under the hood? Can I also do something like that without generating unique keys?

Comment: What is the need of key if it is always 0?

Comment: read more about [shmget(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special key `0` is also known in the `shmget(2)` system call as `IPC_PRIVATE`.  This means there is no "public" key for the segment, and anyone wishing to use it must obtain a reference to it some other way.  For example, a server process which calls `fork(2)` to spawn worker processes may use "private" shared memory to communicate with those workers.  It doesn't need a key because it's only explicitly opened once, before the fork.